# Mute/Unmute Sound w/o Button HTML5

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, mute

Problem: Finding an efficient function for **Muting and Unmuting** Audio (w/o VideoPlayer) in **HTML5** automatically until a defined time is past.

I set the gain of an oscillator to increase gradually from 0 to 1 (interrupted by a bunch of 1second of silence in each unit of gain's increase) until 30s are reached. For this purpose the **setValueAtTime** function (I added increments to both values of gain and time) was called.

It doesn't seem efficient, however, because the iterations don't follow an accurate real-life-corresponding time, even if the arguments are set individually to change values in a particular time -> this demanded a dummy effort to test. More interesting would be **setValueCurveAtTime** and **setLinearRampAtTime**, but they don't seem to allow a distribution of "silences" during the increasing tone.

The only references found regarded UserInteraction with a custom button, which is not automatic; and JQuery functions. I found no documentation precise enough. The function "document.getElementById(id).setVolume(0);" for example doesn't offer neither an option of defining the duration of the silence, nor the option to insert this 1s of silence homogeneously along the 30seconds of an increasing tone.

Once the function is defined, I would call **setTimeout** so that it played immediately and then **setInterval**("function()", 30000).

Snippet of code

```
context=new AudioContext();
var oscillator = context.createOscillator();
var gainR = context.createGain(); 
oscillator.connect(gainR);
gainR.connect(context.destination);
gainR.gain.setValueAtTime(0,currenttime);
loudnessup = function (){
var c = currenttime;
var Loud=0.2; 
gainR.gain.setValueAtTime(Loud, c+2);
gainR.gain.setValueAtTime(0, c+3);
gainR.gain.setValueAtTime(Loud+0.05, c+3.5);
gainR.gain.setValueAtTime(0, c+4.5);
//...continues iterations
gainR.gain.setValueAtTime(Loud+0.8, c+28);
gainR.gain.setValueAtTime(0, c+30);};
setTimeout("loudnessup()",currenttime); 
setInterval(function(){
n=n+1; //after 30s the freq value should arise accordingly to an array 
oscillator.frequency.value = frequencies[n];},30000);}
```

After the 30s, the loop w/ a higher freq doesn't seem to go any further

Comment: Please break up your question so that it's more readable. Paragraphs work.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, j08691. Hope it's also clear enough

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, Katja. Unfortunately, if we are to help you, we need to see the code you are working with. Creating a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) will help get this question answered. Otherwise, it may risk being closed as "too broad".

Comment: Thanks, Tyler! Will make sure I use that for my next contributions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the built-in high-resolution timer to set the volume over a short segment relative to the start time.

It will create two events for each segment to ramp volume quickly. Each segment is toggled so the first time it will ramp up the volume, the second time ramp it down. Using a slight ramp will also prevent clicks in the sound.

Using a toggle state you can create two events defining a short ramp for each segment. If the toggle is true if will go from current volume to 0, otherwise from 0 to current volume:

```
var toggle = true;
var now = actx.currentTime;
...

for(var i = 0; i < duration; i += step) {
    var volume = i / duration;

    g.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(toggle ? volume : 0, now + i);
    g.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(toggle ? 0 : volume, now + i + 0.012);
    toggle = !toggle;
}
```

### Live example

```js
document.querySelector("button").onclick = function() {
  this.style.display = "none";
  playSound();                     // first play
  setInterval(playSound, 30000);   // next play, after and every 30 sec.
};
  
function playSound() {
  
  var duration = 30, step = 1, toggle = false,
      actx = new (AudioContext || webkitAudioContext)(),
      osc = actx.createOscillator(),
      g = actx.createGain();

  osc.frequency.value = 440;
  g.gain.value = 0;
  osc.connect(g); 
  g.connect(actx.destination);

  var now = actx.currentTime;

  for(var i = 0; i < duration; i += step) {
    // volume for this segment when toggled on
    var volume = i / duration;
    
    // create a short ramp using two events 12ms appart
    g.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(toggle ? volume : 0, now + i);
    g.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(toggle ? 0 : volume, now + i + 0.012);
    toggle = !toggle;
  }

  osc.start();
  osc.stop(now + duration);
};
```

```css
button {font:bold 20px sans-serif}
```

```html
<button>Start</button>
```

Comment: Thanks Ken! setInterval doesn't seem to call this function every 30s though...is it because of time inaccuracy (while the first loop is still rolling)? 

    for (var i=0; i<2000; i++){setInterval ("mute.unmute.function()",30000);
    var n=0; 
    n=n+1;
    oscillator.frequency.value= frequencies[n];}

Comment: @KatjaShaniare I updated the answer to replay the sound every 30. seconds. Your for loop there create 2000 instances of setInterval which will try to play the sound at once, obviously not good. I did not add, but store the timerID from setInterval if you want to enable cancelling it (ie. clearInterval(timerID)).